# Google Maps International Space Station embed?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to embed the google maps ISS view into a webpage? You can embed regular google maps or streetview but I can't see a way to make it work with the International Space Station (ISS) page:

https://www.google.com/maps/space/iss/@29.5602853,-95.0853914,2a,75y,260h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1szChzPIAn4RIAAAQvxgbyEg!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo3.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DzChzPIAn4RIAAAQvxgbyEg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D260%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i10000!8i5000

Here is a jsfiddle showing what I've tried with errors:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmo59dn8/

```
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
        <iframe 
            src   = "https://www.google.com/maps/space/iss/@29.5602853,-95.0853914,2a,75y,202.74h,105.19t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1szChzPIAn4RIAAAQvxgbyEg!2e0!7i10000!8i5000"
            is="x-frame-bypass" 
            class = "wikipedia"
            width       = "640" 
            height      = "360" >
        </iframe>
```

Comment: "I can't see a way to make it work" is too vague.  Can you specify what difficulties you are having or error messages you are seeing, and add any relevant code that you have tried?

Comment: added a jsfiddle link showing the problem

Comment: Apparently that link doesn't like to be embedded in an `<iframe>`. My console says __Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/maps/space/iss/@29.5602853,-95.0853914,2a,75y,202.74h,105.19t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1szChzPIAn4RIAAAQvxgbyEg!2e0!7i10000!8i5000' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.__